# AgGridReact multi sort not working on second,third... columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sorting, ag-grid

I have a AgGridReact where I m trying the multi-sort function, but only the first column selected for sorting is sorted, any other column is not sorted.
I can see the sorting being triggered on 2nd,3rd.... columns, but the data is not sorted.

React with Typescript
`import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";/

```
const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([
    {submission_1: "1221@1", submission_2: "9889@1", suspicious_score: "35000"},
    { submission_1: "1222@1", submission_2: "9889@2", suspicious_score: "32000" },
    { submission_1: "1333@1", submission_2: "7889@1", suspicious_score: "72000" }
]);

const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
    { headerName: 'Submission 1', field: 'submission_1'},
    { headerName: 'Submission 2', field: 'submission_2' },
    { headerName: 'Suspicious Score', field: 'suspicious_score' },
    { headerName: 'Identical', field: 'identical_percent' },
    { headerName: 'Identical Wrong', field: 'identical_incorrect_percent' },
    { headerName: 'Identical Correct', field: 'identical_correct_percent' },
    { headerName: 'Timestamp Overlap', field: 'timestamp_overlap_count_per_question' },
    { headerName: 'Suspicious Activities', field: 'suspicious_activities_count' },
    { headerName: 'Link', field: 'link' }
]);
```

return (
<React.Fragment>

```
   <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{height: 400, width: 600}}>
        <AgGridReact className="ag-theme-alpine"
            rowData={rowData}
            columnDefs={columnDefs}
            defaultColDef={{sortable: true, filter: true }}
            >
            </AgGridReact>
        </div>
```

`

Output ->

1. You can see that first I try to sort by Submission 1(col1) and it sorts in descending order
   [Step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCfNv.png)
2. Now I try to sort Submission 2(col2) in descending order, the grid shows multi sorting functionality (small 1& 2 indexes appear near each column denoting order preferences), BUT the actual data is NOT sorted.
   [Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAaHz.png)
3. If I try to sort col2 first, you can see its sorted accurately
   [Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzBSh.png)
4. Now I try to sort col1, but its unable to sort.[Step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l41g7.png)

So basically only first selected column's data is getting sorted. Can someone please help???

Answer (score 1):

It seems you misunderstood multi-sorting. Grid sorts the whole row, but not individual cell values within the column.

What you have described is the expected behavior.